# РЕШЕНО HTML/CSS. При 100% масштабе страницы, div с id=box растягивается в правую сторону

Tags: html, css

Когда я делаю стопроцентный масштаб страницы, то блок div с id=box ползет вправо, когда делаю меньше масштаб страницы, все выравнивается. Не понимаю как исправить. Смотрел с помощью devtools, оказывается у блока div есть margin, хотя margin не установлен, но даже если поставить его на 0, результат, тот который я жду не выходит. Появляется еще скролл по горизонтали, думаю снова же из за margin

```css
* {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}


/* Основа css */

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: 000;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul,
li {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Геометрические фигуры */

#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #1A1A1A;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 0;
}


/* Header */

header a {
  color: white;
}

.logo {
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 189px;
  margin-left: 27px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu li a {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.menu li {
  margin-right: 117px;
}

.contacs {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 24px;
}


/* first */

.first {
  background: url('../img/cover.svg') no-repeat center top / cover;
}

.name {
  color: white;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-left: 500px;
  padding-top: 245px;
}

.name_2 {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 550px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

button {
  background-color: #F43737;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.but_1 {
  margin-left: 660px;
  padding-bottom: 195px;
  padding-top: 143px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<header id="header" class="header">
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="nav">
      <div id='box'>
        <img src='img/logo.svg' class='logo'>
        <ul class='menu'>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>Наличие</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href='#'>Каталог</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href='#'>Прайс-лист</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href='#'>Контакты</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class='contacs'>
          <li>
            <a href='tel:+79237750331' class='tel'>+79237750331</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href='tel:+79039058666' class='tel'>+79039058666</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href='mail:ag.ngs@ya.ru' class='mail'>ag.ngs@ya.ru</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<section id="first" class="first">
  <div class='container'>
    <h1 class="name">АЛЬЯНС-ГРУПП</h1>
    <h4 class='name_2'>общество с ограниченной отвественностью</h4>
    <p class='but_1'><button>Наличие и цены</button></p>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="availability" class="availability">
  <div class='container'>
    <div id='box'>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="application" class="application">
  <div class='container'>

  </div>
</section>

<section id="mapAndContact" class="mapAndContact">
  <div class='container'>

  </div>
</section>

<footer id="footer" class="footer">
  <div class='container'>

  </div>
</footer>
```

Фото проблемы

[image: При меньшем масштабе]

[image: При 100% масштабе]

Решено:
Я вставил получается в css, в классе container и в id box не width, а max-width.

Comment: скрол из за фиксированной ширины - ```width: 1600px```. Используйте ```max-width: 1600px```

Comment: Я вставил max-width в классе container и в box. И оно помогло!